# How can Firebase database rules avoid overwriting of whole nodes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a simple landing page with a form asking for an email. In order to allow unauthenticated users, the write rule cannot be only on for authenticated users.

However, I realised that using the console on any browser and calling something like the following will eventually delete the whole users node.

```
var updates = {};
updates['/users'] = "";
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Can any security rules prevent whole nodes from simply being overwritten like this?

Comment: You might need to think about what *must* be at the location, rather than what *must not* be at the location.  There are a whole lot of different things (aside from an empty string) that could effectively blow away your data.

Comment: You can use **admin** to update the `users` node when a user registers with email and password and have a rule that only allows admin to do that. `".write": "auth != null && auth.token.isAdmin == true"`